# Achievement Popup notification doesnt appear on cache page

Tags: hooks, caching

I am using achievement module on site , it shows a popup notification when a particular achievement is reached . However due to caching (Authcache for authenticated user) , the popup doesn't appear .

The only way I could thought of is to prevent the site from grabbing the cached page ( from cache_page) when the criteria for showing pop is satisfied .

Any pointers on how can it be done ?

Thanks , 
Murali

There is custom module which triggers the pop up :

```
   function geld_achievements_pks_response($user_id) {

   $current_count = achievements_storage_get('forum-node-count', $user_id) +      5;
   achievements_storage_set('forum-node-count', $current_count, $user_id);



   if ($current_count == 25) {
       achievements_unlocked('Level 1', $user_id);
       }
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how/where the achievements module checks for that criteria? Can you give a pointer to the relevant source code?

Comment: Hi Znerol I have updated my question with the code , where the pop is triggered .

Comment: You could place the notification in a block, and not cache the block? Not ideal, but I can't think of a better way off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping on this issue . I finally got it working by a small hack . Authcache does'nt render page from cache if there are outstanding drupal messages . so when the condition for popup is met i , put drupal_set_message('!', warning) . The next page is avoided from cache to display the drupal message ( which I hide by css ) and the pop up . subsequently on clearance of messages the autcache begins fetching cache until the next condition of pop up is met .

Comment: Take a look at [hook_authcache_preclude](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/authcache/tree/authcache.api.php#n84). It allows you to supply your own logic in order to determine whether the next page should be served from the cache or not.